# Icon keeps disappearing from app drawer in CM9

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-mini-pro, adw.launcher

I installed [Cyanogenmod 9.0.0 mango](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=stable&device=mango) on my Xperia mini pro. Everything works fine...except for the built-in launcher's app drawer. What happens is that every time I reboot the phone, the rightmost app shortcut / widget / icon that I place in the app drawer keeps disappearing.

[image]

I can replace the icon and it stays there, but only as long as I don't reboot the phone. Why is this happening and / or how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a further update to the Xperia Mini Pro, probably 9.1 is way to go, might fix up that known issue. Check on the CyanogenMod page for [Xperia Mini Pro](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=stable&device=mango).